# AWS ALB 504 Gateway timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a alb `http://exam-01-alb-xxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/` this returns the website as expected.

but when i try this `http://exam-01-alb-xxxxxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/cgi-bin/exam-02.cgi` its **returns a 504 gateway time out.**

As per my understanding, i think this is a path-based routing problem where a rule needs to be added for the path and attach a target group. but after reading this on docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504 i think idle time out is too small to reach to target group,
**environment:-** single ec2 instance with webserver and single target group with default rule

Note :- i cant modify the client's environment

Comment: Does you application work without ALB? Can you access it by using instance ip directly?

Comment: No,@Marcin, trying to access instance IP results in a timeout as security group for the instance does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Listener in ALB you get 1 "Default Rule". This Default Rule has the port number mentioned and forwards the traffic to any Target Group.

If you want to create a path based Rule then you add Rules in the same listener. In your case path being "cgi-bin". But if you don't add a separate rule then all your traffic will be forwarded to the Default rule (Default Target Group also).

So you have to verify if the path you're trying to access really exists. Is the path on the same Target Group or not.

Comment: Even i thought so but after reading this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504 i am in a dilemma, check my question i have updated it.